# Exposing buttons from child controls to parent controls

Tags: wpf, toolbar

This is more of an architecture design question, and so it wouldn't have code snippets associated with it.

I have a top-level Window class, which has a Toolbar. The Window class might be used to host various content. That content might have Commands available to act on it. The Window can't be aware of what those Commands are. I want those Commands (with associated images, probably) to be available to the Window.

What are the best solutions for this?

One of the ideas I'm bouncing around in my head is to have an attached property that contains a set of Buttons, and for the Window to find children that have this attached property, and put those buttons in it's toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track, but think about exposing the commands instead of the buttons themselves. In whatever mechanism you have to host the content in the window, you can look through what commands are available and add them to the toolbar. You could create a small utility class to hold a command and its associated icon. And have an AvailableCommands collection. Just try to keep the behavior and data as separate from the UI as possible. Then, the window can decide the best way to visually represent those commands, whether its a toolbar, right-click menu, whatever.